# Parallax and redshift - has anyone used Gaia data to match objects with redshift data?

Tags: distance, redshift, parallax

Given the recent Gaia parallax data out to large distances, has anyone used that data to match objects with observed redshift data?

I have taken as much Gaia object data as I can and compared it with some Sloan survey redshift and other data but an find no matching objects that appear in both, so far. I am looking for data that has both redshift and parallax for the same objects out as far as possible, beyond where local effects intrude.
Cheers
Mike

Comment: Gaia is measuring stars in the Milky Way. They don't show a cosmological red shift because the gravitational field of the galaxy overwhelms the expansion of the universe.

Comment: @JohnRennie This should be the answer.

Comment: John, Many thanks. However Gaia has data extending out to a parallax of  0.007mas so around 10^11 Ly which I think is useful to consider - though not much at this distance, mostly over 0.07mas. If you can see a source with the naked eye, then it is too bright for Gaia, so they will take anything that does not overwelm the detector, Milky Way or not.